# get difference of four date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code for 2 date columns difference query is fine.
but when i want to join their result, i am getting error

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Stat_EndTime, Stat_StartTime), 0), 108) AS [VisitTime],
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Load_EndTime, Load_StartTime), 0), 108) AS [LoadTime]
```

When i did a join as below for the complete difference time, i am getting error

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Stationary_EndTime, Stationary_StartTime), 0), 108) - CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,LoadingEndTime, LoadingStartTime), 0), 108) AS [Actual Contact Time],
```

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The error is being **very** explicit here. Especially as you are **converting** your dates to a `varchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a subtraction, not a `JOIN`.  The error is pretty clear.  You are trying to subtract to strings.  That is not allowed.

You can take the difference of two date times:

```
(DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS, Stationary_EndTime, Stationary_StartTime), 0) -
 DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS, LoadingEndTime, LoadingStartTime), 0)
) AS Difference
```